# building RPM package: force to install in path of a dependent relocated package

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have 2 dependent packages who should be placed in the same target. Package B is dependent on package A.

Package A can be relocated to any another location. 
I now want package B forced to be placed in the same target as package A. Or simply, package B should not be able to install without the same --prefix.

Any ideas how to acieve this?

I thought of putting a %pre script to check this. But thats not helpful I think, since I can't read the given "prefix" in this script - or can I?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you know of a way to query a package for the prefix it was installed with at all? I don't offhand (but I've never tried). That being said you don't need to do that if you can instead just check whether *your* prefix has files you depend on underneath it. (Actually I wonder if file prerequisites can be affected by the given prefix.)

Comment: yes, that is `rpm -qa --queryformat '%{instprefixes}' NAME_OF_PACKAGE`

Comment: Interesting. So was the question about getting the prefix for the *current* package then? Does `%{DEFAULTPREFIX}` or `%{INSTALLPREFIX}` get expanded correctly in `%pre` based on the argument?

Comment: no, they don't get expanded. and yes, getting the prefix for the current package (package B) would be sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah. So I did a bit of source diving and discovered that apparently (at least for rpm 4.8.0 I didn't look at other versions) the `RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX` and `RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX#` environment variables are set for the `%pre` (and possibly other scriptlets) to the values of (what appear to be the `%{INSTPREFIXES}` and/or `%{INSTALLPREFIX}` macros). [[source link](http://rpm.org/gitweb?p=rpm.git;a=blob;f=lib/psm.c;h=48b4d3476972112128d055d2344117b4bb105ac1;hb=00711e52f70f8273a3bae39e41e6b3c903b6b73b#l584)]

I would try those in your `%pre` script. They look like they will give you what you want.

[Same code in rpm head.](http://rpm.org/gitweb?p=rpm.git;a=blob;f=lib/rpmscript.c#l198)

Comment: But that would be for the package being installed, not the *other* package he is trying to match...

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco He can query `rpm` for the prefix of the installed package during `%pre` I presume (or just search the current package's prefix for the known files he depends on from the other package).